# whitelist function usage in python

Tags: whitelist

I am new to python . would like to know what is the use of whitelist( know it can be used as set) and does it matter on the IDE's used like IDLE and anaconda etc ? In IDLE it always shows whitelist is not defined .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not an in-built object in Python that is called `whitelist`. I only know whitelisting as a "procedure", e.g., if you want to return some values (e.g., from a string search) "whitelisting" would give you all the positive results (matches) and blacklisting all the negative results (non-matches).

I assume that you might saw a variable "whitelist" that was defined in a certain context and it has nothing to do with Python in general. It would definitely help if you could provide some more context or info about the source where you saw the "whitelist".

Comment: import sys
import string

def main():
    WHITELIST = ('1', '2')

Comment: WHEN I TRY TO RUN IN IDLE IT GIVES AN ERROR WHITELIST IS NOT DEFINED .

Comment: Okay, so whitelist IS a variable (more specific: a tuple) that is assigned in the current session and has nothing to do with the imports.

Comment: No offense, but just a good advice. Maybe you want to read some introductory Python books before you spend so much time to tracking down those things (it will become clear immediately if you go through some beginner material). Basically, it is nothing else than something like `my_string = 'hello world'; print(my_string)` (<- a simple assignment + function call)

Comment: sure will take a look